# process to disable cross domain request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, content-security-policy

i want to disable cross domain ajax request.

what i mean is if im posting data through ajax call like

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadfiles.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function( ) {
                        $(".progressbar").show();
                },
            xhr: function() {  
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if(xhr.upload){ 
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', showProgress, false);
                    }
                    return xhr;
            },
            success: function(data){
                if( percentComplete <= 100 ) {
                        $('#pb div').animate({ width: '100%' }, { step: function(now) {
                                $(this).text( Math.round(now) + '%' );
                        },  duration: 10});
                    ajaxLoading = false;
                        }
               $('#uplcomp').append( data );
            }
        });
    }
```

if any one trying to post to **uploadfiles.php** through ajax request from their domain , how can i prevent to access uploadfiles.php

I want to allow only from my domain to send data through ajax call

After googling i found this solution:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.info")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

where exactly i have to use the above code. in uploadfiles.php ?

**updated :**
i have used in uploadfiles.php

displays : **notice**

```
**Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN**
```

**Updated 2**

how can use this statement

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

do i have to mention this php config files or in **filesupload.php**

what exactly the above statement will do?

Comment: Yes, you have to use that code in uploadfiles.php

Comment: This should be blocked server side, as your js has no way of knowing when another client posts to that URL. And personally I'm against this technique as it's more about control than security. You should *always* check any incoming data regardless of origin and have ( if necessary ) some sort of mechanism in place ( like a granted token ) to validate sanctioned request/post.

Comment: Also, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` won't save you as it just blocks legitimate browsers that are making ajax requests and checking if the cross-origin request from their current domain is allowed by remote server or if they should enforce normal Same-Origin policy. It doesn't prevent non-ajax direct requests from an HTTP client like cUrl.

Comment: On your server side, check if user is authorized. I mean if a user is logged in, then allow him further.

Comment: @Wexoni thats a bad idea...

Comment: @Anthony then what exactly i have to do... to prevent...!

Comment: We allow on our server anyone to hit the controller, but only those that are authorized will be allowed further passage.

Comment: Also, check the headers on server side and make logic to handle headers and make decision what to allow, and what not to allow

Comment: One of the solutions would be filter requests by IP address.

Comment: @prassu - to prevent what? Spam? DoS attacks? Uploads from non-validated users? As Wexoni says, if you need the uploads to only come from authenticated users, use session variables and some sort of authentication process on the upload script. If anyone can upload and you need to defend against garbage, use either a CAPTCHA or server-side scan of input before saving. If you need to prevent against DoS, use IP-based throttling. But Headers can be left off by some browsers, and spoofed by those who are clever, so simply checking that the request says it's from your site is never 100% reliable.

Comment: as i have mentioned in my question filesupload.php shouldnot get accessed by third party website using ajax posting or what ever... only my website should be allowed to access uploadfiles.php file... As of now third party websites can access my php file using cross domain ajax request ryt? @Anthony

Comment: Well, hold your breath and wish real hard and see how well woulda and shoulda work out.

Comment: so what do you mean... ? is it possible or not ?